# Can I set myself on fire infinitely?

Tags: team-fortress-2

How do you set yourself alight for an infinite amount of time? I've tried all the conditions and the closest I've come is condition 22, which only makes your character complain about fire for a split second, but it doesn't set you alight.

Comment: What makes you think this is possible?  What is this "condition 22" you speak of?  Are you sure you're not thinking of the strange hats with particle effects?

Comment: @SouthpawHare "condition 22" is one of the possibilities for the addcond cheat: http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Cheats#addcond

Comment: Do you have proof that it is possible to set yourself alight for an infinite amount of time?

Comment: @AustinMohr I don't actually. But I'm pretty confident there is.

Comment: @SouthpawHare He's talking about setting himself on fire, not for a Burning particle effect. I assume the OP want to use the B.A.S.E. Jumper to fly around the map forever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no vanilla cheat commands to do what you say...

**However,** there are 2 things you can do to achieve what you say.

**1.** Enable buddha mode so you don't die by fire.

**2.** From a dedicated SourceMod server (or offline listen server), create a [trigger multiple dynamically using this plugin](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?p=2018035) and add the output (OnTrigger !activator igniteplayer).

This usage is shown in [achievement_idle_inferno](http://tf2.gamebanana.com/maps/118302), and as I have tested is able to set you on fire infinitely while inside and can activate the B.A.S.E jumper forever unless you die.

Cheers, and hope you can work it out with this strategy.

Answer (score -2):

Have a enemy pyro bot following you together with a friendly medic.